# weird error - increasing month by one - Python+MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

2017-05-12 is inserted in to MySQL as 2017-06-12 - couldn't figure out with debugging...pasted the key parts of code

Windows platform; Used PyMySQL; If the issue isnt resolved, i will probably bulk update the table to reduce the month by one...i guess that should be easy...

```
exceptions = []
flag = 'N'

def obtain_list_of_db_tickers():
"""
Obtains a list of the ticker symbols in the database.
"""
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT id, ticker FROM symbol")
    data = cur.fetchall()

list1,list2 = map(list,zip(*data))
uniqtickers = list(set(list2))
rangelist = list(range(1,len(uniqtickers)+1))

newtickers = list(zip(rangelist,uniqtickers))

return [(d[0], d[1]) for d in newtickers]


def get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(
    ticker, start_date=(2017,5,12),
    end_date=datetime.date.today().timetuple()[0:3]
) :

""""
Obtains data from Yahoo Finance returns and a list of tuples
ticker: Yahoo Finance ticker symbol eg: GOOG
start_date: Start date in (YYYY,M,D) format
End_date: End date in (YYYY,M,D) format
"""

# Construct the Yahoo URL with the correct integer query parameters
# for start and end dates. Note that some parameters are zero-based!

ticker_tup = (
    ticker, start_date[1]-1, start_date[2],
    start_date[0], end_date[1]-1, end_date[2],
    end_date[0]
)

yahoo_url = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv"
yahoo_url += "?s=%s&a=%s&b=%s&c=%s&d=%s&e=%s&f=%s"
yahoo_url = yahoo_url % ticker_tup

# Try connecting to Yahoo Finance and obtaining the data
# On failure, print an error message.
global flag

try:
    yf_data = pd.read_csv(yahoo_url)

    yf_data['Date'] = yf_data['Date'].apply(lambda x: 
   datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))

    prices = yf_data.set_index(['Date'])[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 
'Volume', 'Adj Close']].to_records().tolist()

except Exception as e:
    print("Could not download Yahoo data: %s" %e)
    flag = 'Y'
    exceptions.append(ticker)
    return None

return prices



def insert_daily_data_into_db(
    data_vendor_id, symbol_id, ticker, daily_data
):

"""
Takes a list of tuples of daily data and adds it to the
MySQL database. Appends the vendor ID and symbol ID to the data.

daily_data: List of tuples of the OHLC data(with adj_close and volume)
"""

# Create the time now
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

#Amend the data to include the vendor ID and symbol IDprices
daily_data = [
    (data_vendor_id, symbol_id, ticker, d[0], now, now,
     d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6])
    for d in daily_data
]

# Create the insert strings
column_str = """data_vendor_id, symbol_id, ticker, price_date, created_date,
last_updated_date, open_price, high_price, low_price,
close_price, volume, adj_close_price"""


insert_str = ("%s, " *12)[:-2]
final_str = "INSERT INTO daily_price (%s) VALUES (%s)" %\
            (column_str, insert_str)

# Using the MySQL connection, carry out an INSERT INTO for every symbol
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.executemany(final_str, daily_data)




if __name__ == "__main__":
# This ignores the warnings regarding Data Truncation
# from the Yahoo precision to Decimal(19,4) datatypes
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# Loop over the tickers and insert the daily historical
# data into the database


tickers = obtain_list_of_db_tickers()
lentickers = len(tickers)

for i, t in enumerate(tickers):
    print(
    "Adding data for %s: %s out of %s" %
    (t[1], i+1, lentickers)
     )

    yf_data = get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(t[1])

    if (flag == 'N'):
        insert_daily_data_into_db('1', t[0], t[1], yf_data)
    elif (flag == 'Y'):
        flag = 'N'
```

Comment: Log what you are sending to `cur.executemany` and the issue should be apparent.  It isn't obvious what might explain what might be happening, but it should go without saying that there's no standard explanation for dates being off by a month.

Comment: This is getting even weird - i saw the log and it is showing correct date of 2007-05-12; I even went to the table and used "select month(created_date) from daily_price" and it is showing 5 as well - but when i display with select * it is showing 2007-06-12 - cant understand this??? are there any mysql settings? This definetly doesnt seem to be a code issue.